# Compound interest with compounding fee included

Tags: investing, tax-deduction

I have found plenty of compounding interest spreadsheets but none that include the relevant investment fee.

example
First column is the sub headings:
A1/ Initial Principle
A2/ Annual Interest Rate
A3/ Annual fee
A4/ Compounding periods per year
A5/ Number of years
A6/ Final Amount

Second column is the numbers:
C1/ total amount in currency
C2/ Interest amount in %
C3/ Number of compounding periods in numerical
C4/ number of years
C5/ FEE %

Below is the formula i have used for final amount

=C1*(1+C2/C3)^(C3*C4)

How would i include the fee in this?

Also how would i show the total fee & interest incurred after the set number of years?

Any help truly appreciated.

Comment: How often is the fee applied? Annually?

Comment: It also matters how the fee is structured: a percentage of total amount? A percentage of gains?

Answer (score 1):

If the fee is applied annually, you would first get the annual returns, then adjust for the annual fee, then compound for `C4` years, so the formula would be:

```
=C1*((((1+C2/C3)^C3)*(1-C5))^C4)
```

Note that `(1+C2/C3)^C3` is just the *annualized* growth rate of the account, and if you call that A, then the formula simplifies to:

```
=C1*((A*(1-C5))^C4)
```

Comment: "and if you call that A, then the formula simplifies to:" I think you vacillated a bit on whether to represent it with A or X.